# Change resolution - zoom resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, zooming

I use a big screen 4K 43", of course the resolution 4K makes everything too small on screen.

On windows, I have a option to zoom all the desktop GUI, normally I use 150%.

Is there a way to do the same on linux? I'm using Ubuntu Studio latest version. I can change the resolution to FHD but than the things are tooooo big.

Thx for any help.

Comment: Any of the answers here worked. Not Xrandr scale and etc. I can change the resolution, but not zoom the resolution.